# Shiny node reactivity dependency tree

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I have started to maintain an Rshiny package of ~3000 code lines. I would like to get an overview of what is triggering what in the server.R file.

Is there by chance a neat way to generate a reactivity trigger dependency chart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be interesting to you: https://www.r-bloggers.com/announcing-shinytester-a-package-that-helps-you-build-shiny-apps/

It introduces a library called `shinyTester` with the function 
`ShinyHierarchy()`.
For an example from that article see the picture below.
[image]

Comment: I do like that package, didn't know about it. Will be trying it out on something big one of these days.

Comment: This might be a better bet if you have a lot of nodes and want to analyze it carefully and statically. The built-in visualizer that I posted below though is very instructive as you can see how the dependencies are actually built up and tracked dynamicly - something a static tool cannot really capture. But it also gets confusing very fast.

Comment: You are right Mike, they probably should be used both. I wasnt aware of the "reactive log visualizer". Concerning the "size" of the shiny app, it could be interesting if one can (add) a functionality within `ShinyHierachy()` which enables you to filter for part of the shiny app so that you can control the size of the chart.

Answer (score 9):

There is a shiny "reactive log visualizer" built into shiny. It builds up a graph incrementally that shows how the various reactive nodes depend on each other. Its output after a run looks like this:

[image]

Instructions on using this tool can be found here:[Reactive Log Visualizer](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/showReactLog.html)

These are my notes on this tool:

- It is enabled with the line `options(shiny.reactlog = TRUE)` inserted before the shinyApp call
- It causes a log to be recorded of how the nodes activate each other.
- The log visualizer can then be enabled with `Ctrl-F3` (or `Command-F3` on Apple)
- There is a node layouter that can be manually overridden. It can be challenging when a lot of nodes are displayed to keep the lines from crossing each other.
- You can then move back in forth in the log (basically you are moving in time in the log) with the arrow keys.
- The reactive symbols are explained here: [Shiny Reactivity Overview](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html)
- It exposes a lot of reactive activity that is invisible to the user so it can be confusing.
- It does not work well on large Shiny applications - many aspects of this tool simply do not scale.

Comment: this answer was super useful also, thx. It seems shinyTester will miss some events due to the mentioned caveats. Reactive log visualizer logs everything, almost too much :)

Comment: Thanks. Will do a pros and cons list of static vs. dynamic shiny node analyzers when I get around to it.

Comment: Thanks for the overview! A small remark, for "Shiny Reactivity Overview" the link is missing, i think.

Comment: Do you know where the log is found in text on the server so I can use other tools to parse it?

Comment: I would have to look and I will later and add that to the answer,

Comment: @MikeWise Thanks Mike, I would really appreciate that

Comment: See the answer I posted. The reactive log is stored as an unexported global (`shiny:::.graphStack`) and not available anywhere externally. It is written to the log visualizer output though, which you can see by inspecting the value of `window.log` in a Javascript console.

Answer (score 6):

The reactive log visualizer is a powerful tool, but unfortunately doesn't scale well with larger apps as @Mike Wise noted. A while ago I read some interesting ideas for improving the debugging experience in [rstudio/shiny#1846](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1846) and [rstudio/shiny#1532](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1532), and started exploring ways to implement them.

After stumbling a bit here and there ([summary](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1846#issuecomment-361831280)), I found that the best way to do this was to parse the raw reactive log and construct a dependency graph from it.

Package at https://github.com/glin/reactlog. The two main features are:

Showing the call stack that triggered invalidation

```
observe({
  reactlog::traceInvalidation()
  rx()
})
```

```
4: observe({
       reactlog::traceInvalidation()
       rx()
   })
3: rx [<text>#7]
2: val =>  num 10
1: observe(val(10))
```

and listing reactive dependencies in a tree view

```
observe({
  reactlog::listDependencies()
  rxA() + rxB() + rxAB()
}, label = "obs")
```

```
obs*
+-- rxA*
| `-- valA*
+-- rxB
| `-- valB
`-- rxAB*
  +-- valA*
  `-- valB
```

A tree view might be particularly useful to see if multiple dependencies were invalidated (asterisks denote invalidation or change).